# Accessing cshtml in referenced webapi project

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

Azure function app references a `webApi` project which uses `razorEngine` to build `cshtml` view.

The problem is accessing the cshtml file. Till now I was using:

`HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Views/templates/") + "test.cshtml";`

to access the file which used to work with webApi as a standalone project. Now as a referenced assembly the path evaluates to

`E:\Web\Proj.Func\bin\Debug\net461\test.cshtml`

which doesn't evaluate to be the right path to the `cshtml` file.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is the file "test.cshtml" getting copied into Debug folder?

Comment: Debug folder doesn't contain `test.cshtml`

Comment: Try setting the copyAlways property to true in properties of test.cshtml file in visual studio and see if that helps?

Comment: Doesn't, tried. Actually the referenced assembly is just a DLL.

Comment: Maybe you should try embedding your cshtml.

Comment: Why do you want to use Azure Functions instead of a Web API instance hosted in Azure?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev As I am sending multiple emails at once. CPU and Memory loading at this particular moment is high. With Azure Functions I can save on money and at the same time there's no limit on memory and cpu consumption.

Comment: There is an option to use another Razor templates parser implementation in order to not modify existing Web API project. Hovewer, non-Microsoft implementations are different in some respects from Razor view engine used in ASP.NET MVC. For more information check [About Razor and its syntax](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/AboutRazor.html) page in RazorEngine docs and [Taking a step back: behind the scenes of Razor and RazorEngine](http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-part-04-taking-a-step-back-behind-the-scenes-of-razor-and-razorengine/) article by Mehdi El Gueddary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a Web API project as a reference to another project, and use it like a Class Library, then `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` will not work. In fact the api controller in no more hosted and `HostingEnvironment.IsHosted` is false.

As an option you can write the code to find the file like following code, then the code will work in both cases, when it's hosted as Web API or when it's been used as a Class Library.

Just don't forget to include the files to output directory, so they will be copied near the bin folder of the Azure Function project.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Http;
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        var relative = "Views/templates/test.cshtml";
        var abosolute = "";
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
            abosolute = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/{0}", relative));
        else
        {
            var root = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).Parent.FullName;
            abosolute = Path.Combine(root, relative.Replace("/", @"\"));
        }
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(abosolute);
    }
}
```

And here is the function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("Running");
    var api = new MyApiController();
    var result = await Task.Run(() => api.Get());
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I solved it. Just instead of having path code directly in the `ApiController`. I utilized a separate service whose method is referred to by both `WebApi` and `Azure Func`. Will wait for 1-2 days before selecting this as an answer.

Comment: Great! Yes, it's just an example and to keep things simple, I just put the whole code in controller.

Comment: What's the purpose of `Task.Run()` use?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev To satisfy the compiler and prevent it from complaining. It's not required.

Comment: You can remove `async` modifier and replace `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` return type with `HttpResponseMessage`. `Get()` function use synchronous file IO anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
AppContext.BaseDirectory + "Views\\templates\\" + "test.cshtml"
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: `C:\Users\Shyamal\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.7\Views\templates\test.cshtml`

Could not find path.